# uploading video to Facebook error 5

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, file-upload

I am trying to upload a video from my iPhone to Facebook.  I have logged in using FBLoginView and created a FBSession.  I have used the following code to initiate a FBRequest of upload the video.

```
- (void)buttonRequestClickHandler:(id)sender {

if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

    [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:permissions
                                    defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe
                                        completionHandler:nil];        

    NSString *audioName = [pictureDictionary4 objectForKey:@"photoVideokey"];
    NSArray *pathsa = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectorya = [pathsa objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *moviePath = [documentsDirectorya stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Movie"];
    NSString *fullPatha = [moviePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:audioName];
    NSURL *pathURL = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:fullPatha isDirectory:NO];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPatha];

    NSString *titleString = self.videotitle.text;
    NSString *descripString = self.descrp.text;

    NSDictionary *videoObject = @{
                                  @"title":titleString,
                                  @"description": descripString,
                                  [pathURL absoluteString]: videoData
                                  };
    FBRequest *uploadRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                                    parameters:videoObject
                                                    HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

   [uploadRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
            NSLog(@"Done: %@", result);
        else
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
}
```

I get an error
Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

I'm not sure what the error pertains to:

I know I'm logged in

I don't know if I am getting connected but I am on internet with iPhone

Are my parameters incorrect?
I have been messing with this for HOURS with no results
Any help from anyone/everyone would be greatly appreciated.

Finally got this working by going into my iPhone settings-facebook and deleting my account. Then when I tapped to upload the video in my app it loaded a view that asked if Facebook could use my app and I said yes then bam it uploaded. Also had to change my permissions to just publish_actions and get rid of publish_streams since that is a read permission. Anyway it is working now. Next to get defaultAudience to load from a string picked by user and not hard coded. Another post.

Answer (score 0):

I guess its something to do with stream publishing permission. Try this way. It worked for me. I was using Facebook SDK 3.8.0

```
    [self performPublishAction:^{

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"faisal" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSURL *pathURL = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSDictionary *videoObject = @{
                                  @"title": @"This is my title",
                                  @"description": @"This is my description",
                                  [pathURL absoluteString]: videoData
                                  };
    FBRequest *uploadRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                                    parameters:videoObject
                                                    HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [uploadRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
            NSLog(@"Done: %@", result);
        else
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
}];
```

and

```
- (void) performPublishAction:(void (^)(void)) action {
if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_stream"] == NSNotFound) {
    [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_stream"]
                                          defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                        completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                            if (!error) {
                                                action();
                                            } else if (error.fberrorCategory != FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled){
                                                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Permission denied"
                                                                                                    message:@"Unable to get permission to post"
                                                                                                   delegate:nil
                                                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                [alertView show];
                                            }
                                        }];
} else {
    action();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code is Tested successfully On **[FaceBook SDK 3.14.1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/)**

**Recommendation:** 3 properties in .plist file

set FacebookAppID,FacebookDisplayName,
URL types->Item 0->URL Schemes   set to facebookappId prefix with `fb` **[See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZAXQ.png)**

```
-(void)shareOnFaceBook
{
    //sample_video.mov is the name of file
    NSString *filePathOfVideo = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample_video" ofType:@"mov"];

    NSLog(@"Path  Of Video is %@", filePathOfVideo);
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePathOfVideo];
    //you can use dataWithContentsOfURL if you have a Url of video file
    //NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:shareURL];
    //NSLog(@"data is :%@",videoData);
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               videoData, @"video.mov",
                               @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                               @"Video name ", @"name",
                               @"description of Video", @"description",
                               nil];

   if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
   {
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                              if(!error)
                              {
                                  NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", result);
                                  [self throwAlertWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Video uploaded"];
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                  [self throwAlertWithTitle:@"Denied" message:@"Try Again"];
                              }
                          }];
    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"publish_actions",
                            nil];
        // OPEN Session!
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone  allowLoginUI:YES
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState status,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         if (error)
                                         {
                                             NSLog(@"Login fail :%@",error);
                                         }
                                         else if (FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status))
                                         {
                                             [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                                                          parameters:params
                                                                          HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                                                                   completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                                                       if(!error)
                                                                       {
                                                                           [self throwAlertWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Video uploaded"];

                                                                           NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", result);
                                                                       }
                                                                       else
                                                                       {
                                                                           [self throwAlertWithTitle:@"Denied" message:@"Try Again"];

                                                                           NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                                                       }

                                                                   }];
                                         }
                                     }];
        }
}
```

And I GOT Error:

```
 The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)
```

It happens when facebook is being inited. Next time i open my app, it works fine, its always the first time. Tried everything in app, but it seems to be on the Facebook SDK side.

Few causes for seeing `com.facebook.sdk error 5`:

- Session is is not open. Validate.
- Facebook has detected that you're spamming the system. Change video name.
- Facebook has a defined limit using the SDK. Try a different app.
- Wrong publish permission. Give `publish_actions` a spin.