# Uploading video to Facebook from iOS app using SDK 3.6 intermittently failing

Tags: ios, facebook, video, upload

I'm using Facebook SDK 3.6 within an iOS 6.3 app to upload a video to Facebook.

I've looked over many Stack Overflow posts about this but they are all years old and using much older Facebook SDKs.

Sometimes it works, other times it fails with the following message:

```
unexpected error:Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be     completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x1e2affc0 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=500, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
body = {
"error_code" = 1;
"error_msg" = "An unknown error occurred";
};
code = 500;
}, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=, expirationDate: 4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, refreshDate: 2013-07-30 10:54:22 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
"publish_stream"
)>}
```

Here is my code:

```
FBRequestConnection *_currentConnection;

[FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_stream"]
                                          defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe
                                        completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                            if (!error) {

NSError *attributesError;
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:url.path error:&attributesError];

NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
long long fileSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue];

NSLog(@"file size: %lld", fileSize);

NSString *filename = [url lastPathComponent];
NSLog(@"filename: %@", filename);
NSString *mimeType = [self MIMETypeForFilename:filename
                                       defaultMIMEType:@"video/mp4"];

NSLog(@"mime type: %@", mimeType);

NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       videoData, filename,
                                       mimeType, @"contentType",
                                       self.song.name, @"title",
                                       _videoDescription, @"description",
                                       nil];




        FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                                  parameters:params
                                                  HTTPMethod:@"POST"];



        _currentConnection = [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

            self.stageLabel.text = @"";

            NSLog(@"result: %@, error: %@", result, error);
            if(error) {
                // Facebook SDK * error handling *
                // if the operation is not user cancelled
                if (error.fberrorCategory != FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
                    [self showAlert:@"Video Post" result:result error:error];
                }

                self.uploadBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
            } else {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Video Uploaded" message:@"Video has been uploaded"
                                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
                [self.delegate facebookUploaderUploadSucceeded:self];
            }

            // Delete the temp video
            NSError *err;
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:_sourceURL error:&err];
            NSLog(@"Deleting video %@: %@", _sourceURL, [err localizedDescription]);


        }];



    }];

}
}];
```

Comment: I also had this same problem. Follow my answer in this [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368081/uploading-video-to-facebook-error-5/18958116#18958116

Answer (score 0):

This Code is Tested successfully On **[FaceBook SDK 3.14.1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/)**

```
-(void)shareOnFaceBook
{
    //sample_video.mov is the name of file
    NSString *filePathOfVideo = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample_video" ofType:@"mov"];

    NSLog(@"Path  Of Video is %@", filePathOfVideo);
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePathOfVideo];
    //you can use dataWithContentsOfURL if you have a Url of video file
    //NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:shareURL];
    //NSLog(@"data is :%@",videoData);
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               videoData, @"video.mov",
                               @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                               @"Video name ", @"name",
                               @"description of Video", @"description",
                               nil];

   if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
   {
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                              if(!error)
                              {
                                  NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", result);
                                  [self throwAlertWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Video uploaded"];
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                  [self throwAlertWithTitle:@"Denied" message:@"Try Again"];
                              }
                          }];
    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"publish_actions",
                            nil];
        // OPEN Session!
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone  allowLoginUI:YES
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState status,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         if (error)
                                         {
                                             NSLog(@"Login fail :%@",error);
                                         }
                                         else if (FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status))
                                         {
                                             [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                                                          parameters:params
                                                                          HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                                                                   completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                                                       if(!error)
                                                                       {
                                                                           [self throwAlertWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Video uploaded"];

                                                                           NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", result);
                                                                       }
                                                                       else
                                                                       {
                                                                           [self throwAlertWithTitle:@"Denied" message:@"Try Again"];

                                                                           NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                                                       }

                                                                   }];
                                         }
                                     }];
        }
}
```

And I GOT Error:

```
 The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)
```

It happens when facebook is being inited. Next time i open my app, it works fine, its always the first time. Tried everything in app, but it seems to be on the Facebook SDK side.

Few causes for seeing `com.facebook.sdk error 5`:

- Session is is not open. Validate.
- Facebook has detected that you're spamming the system. Change video name.
- Facebook has a defined limit using the SDK. Try a different app.
- Wrong publish permission. Give `publish_actions` a spin.